# Can't make ActiveSupport::Duration in Rails settings.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to put a ActiveSupport::Duration value in settings.yml. But a result value in `Settings` has `Fixnum` class:

```
#settings.yml
timeout: <%= 1.hour %>

> Settings.timeout
=> 3600
> Settings.timeout.class
=> Fixnum
> 1.hour.class
=> ActiveSupport::Duration
```

How i can fix it?

I'm using Rails 4.2 with [`config`](https://github.com/railsconfig/config)  gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
#settings.yml
timeout: <%= 1.hour %>

> Settings.timeout
=> 3600
> Settings.timeout.seconds
=> 3600
```

Now it can be used as `ActiveSupport::Duration`

```
> Settings.timeout.seconds.ago
=> Sat, 25 Mar 2017 09:12:39 MSK +03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Coerce the value to an integer using the Ruby `to_i` method:

```
⇒ 1.hour
=> 1 hour
⇒ 1.hour.class
=> ActiveSupport::Duration < Object
⇒ 1.hour.to_i
=> 3600
⇒ 1.hour.to_i.class
=> Fixnum < Integer
```

- More information on `to_i`: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i
- More information on ActiveSupport::Duration: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html

Comment: Unfortunately, i need `ActiveSupport::Duration` in result to use `ago` method. `1.hours.ago` works but `Settings.timeout.to_i.ago` does not